# Observe every rendering (even conditionals) in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to get a function running after any rendering in EmberJS has happened (globally), especially after the "switch" in an {{#if}}-{{else}}-block.

Subscribing to the render event with

```
Ember.subscribe("render", {
    before: function (name, timestamp, payload) {
    },
    after: function (name, timestamp, payload) {
        // function call
    }
});
```

works quite well but is not called after the rerendering via the if-else-switch.

So what I want to do is listen to the rendering globally and be noticed at the end of it.

Best regards
Martin